# Using the fill_between function to plot uncertainty in a line fit: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous."

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

So i'm trying to write a piece of code which will take a linear fit (with given uncertainty in parameters) and plot an uncertainty range. To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
T = np.insert(xdata, 0, absolute_zero)
maxi = lambda x_var: max([
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)])
mini = lambda x_var: min([
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)])
plt.fill_between(T, maxi(T), mini(T))
```

Where the Linear() function is defined as follows:

```
def Linear(p, x):
   factor, constant = p
   return(factor * x + constant)
```

But this code returns the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Though I know that this is probably because I'm giving a non-array function an array I don't know how to solve it, as that's how fill_between works. Trying it in the form:

```
plt.fill_between(T, 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)
)
```

does work, but doesn't give the desired result.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

**Edit:** The more complete code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.odr as ODR

def Linear(p, x):
   factor, constant = p
   return(factor * x + constant)

# Define data
tdata = [20.3, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
vdata = [58, 60, 63, 66, 68, 70, 70, 72]

xdata = np.array(tdata)
xerr = np.array(abs(0.01*xdata))

ydata = np.array(vdata)
yerr = np.ones(len(ydata))

# Fit to the linear model
Linear_model = ODR.Model(Linear)
data = ODR.RealData(xdata, ydata, sx = xerr, sy = yerr)
odr = ODR.ODR(data, Linear_model, beta0 = [0.2, 65])
out = odr.run()
out.pprint()
parameters = out.beta
sd_parameters = out.sd_beta

absolute_zero = -parameters[1]/parameters[0]

print("We find parameters: " + str(parameters) + " $\pm$ " + str(sd_parameters) + ".\n And an absolute 0 of " + str(absolute_zero))

# Start plotting
T = np.insert(xdata, 0, absolute_zero)
maxi = lambda x_var: max([
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)])
mini = lambda x_var: min([
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)])
plt.fill_between(T, maxi(T), mini(T))
plt.plot(T, Linear(parameters, T))
plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, xerr= xerr, yerr=yerr, fmt = '.')
plt.plot([absolute_zero], [0], '.')
plt.text(x=absolute_zero+10, y=-1, s="(0,"+ str(round(absolute_zero,2)) + ")")
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Volume (ml)')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You forgot to tell what the desired result *is*. Since the input is unknown and the output is unknown, what can we do to help you here?

Comment: The desired result is to create bands around a separate line that's fit, and because both the factor as well as the constant can change in the uncertainty, I'd like to colour between the maxima and minima of those changes. That should give a band that never crosses the predicted value of Linear(tuple([parameters[0], parameters[1]], T))

Comment: You probably want to take the minimum and maximum element-wise?! If you provide a [mcve] with some input parameters and defined `T`, I could show you how to do it in the code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the post to include the relevant code. The problem arises when the fill_between function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If being given an array as input, `Linear` will output an array as well. Calculating the minimum of two or more arrays will in general fail, e.g. consider

```
a = np.array([2,5])
b = np.array([3,4])
min([a,b]) # will fail as it is unclear which of the two arrays is smaller
```

Instead you want to find the minimum and maximum **elementwise**. This can easily be done with numpy, taking the minimum along the horizontal axis of an array with columns

```
np.min(np.c_[a,b], axis=1) # returns [2,4]
```

or similarly taking the minimum along the vertical axis of an array with rows

```
np.min(np.r_[a,b], axis=0)
```

In the case from the question, this would look like

```
T = np.insert(xdata, 0, absolute_zero)
maxi = lambda x_var: np.max(np.c_[
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)], axis=1)
mini = lambda x_var: np.min(np.c_[
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var), 
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]+sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]+sd_parameters[1]]), x_var),
                 Linear(tuple([parameters[0]-sd_parameters[0], parameters[1]-sd_parameters[1]]), x_var)], axis=1)
plt.fill_between(T, maxi(T),mini(T) )
```